# Can't see WMS layer when I zoom

Tags: openlayers-2, wms, zoom

I have read many tips for the problem "layer becomes cloudy when zoom", but it doesn't work still. Where is the problem in my source?

```
var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "Földrengések",
    'http:/....../wms',
    {
      layers: ['rengesekk'], 
      isBaseLayer: false,
      transparent: true,
      srs: "EPSG:4612",
      numZoomLevels: 12,
    },
    { singleTile: true
    });
```

[image]